# Google GCM delay, TCP timeout fix?

Tags: android, tcp, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application which depends on sending instant messages. I use google CSS and XMPP to achieve a persistent connection to the GCM server which works well.

But sometimes there is a delay while receiving the messages (10-15 seconds) on the client side (when on 3G), and I need to find a fix. I was reading that TCP connection timeout can occur while mobile operators often kill connection sockets, so I was thinking if there is a way to have a persistent connection with the GCM server on the client side as well?? Or could pinging the server be helpful?

I would be really grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be a battery efficient service , GCM in order to prevent TCP timeout sends a heartbeat every 18 mins on a 3G mobile device and 28 mins on Wifi . That is the reason why messages are delayed . Well one way to fix it is to send that heartbeat every X minutes . Just put the following code in a timer inside a service .

```
  new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Trying to save", "GCM or FCM");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.c"));
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));
        }

    }, 0, 138000{Set this time interval as per your needs;Preferably 5 mins});
```

**CAUTION:** Reducing the time interval may result in draining of device battery so 
chose that wisely.
 This will keep on reviving your connection to GCM servers and you  will recieve notifications on time. Good Luck , let me know if it worked